# Can't pass Multi-Dimensional array to foreach function - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to pass in a multi dimensional array to a foreach statement, when I do, the variable I cast the array to, loses the structure, so it can't be accessed properly.

For example -

```
  $unFilteredInfo = array();

    $sql  - ...
    // execute sql

    $i = 0;
    while ($rows = CDB::GetAssoc($lrs)) 
    {
        $unFilteredInfo["LINE1"][$i] = $rows["LINE1"];
        $unFilteredInfo["LINE2"][$i] = $rows["LINE2"];
        $unFilteredInfo["LINE3"][$i] = $rows["LINE3"];
        $i++;
    }
    // Array filled. 
    $arrayCount = count($unFilteredInfo); // 2547

    $ii = 0;
    foreach ($unFilteredInfo as $info)
    {
        $line1Info= $info["LINE1"]; // null..
        $line2Info= $info["LINE2"]; // null..
        $line3Info= $info["LINE3"]; // null..

        $line1Info= $info["LINE1"][$ii]; // null..
        $line2Info= $info["LINE2"][$ii]; // null..
        $line3Info= $info["LINE3"][$ii]; // null..
    $ii++;
    }
```

Also, when running varDump on $info this is printed -

```
    array (size=2547)
      0 => string 'APPO' (length=4)
      1 => string 'APPX' (length=4)
      2 => string 'APPO' (length=4)
      3 => string 'APPX' (length=4)
      4 => string 'APPI' (length=4)
      5 => string 'APPO' (length=4)
..................................
```

For some reason, when I access the $info variable in the foreach statement, it results in null. I even tried to access the $info row data with a string key and int, still returns null.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you do a `var_dump($info);`? Could you show us the structure / sample data of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding your own array structure. It looks like this:

```
[
    LINE1 => [.., .., ..],
    LINE2 => [.., .., ..],
    LINE3 => [.., .., ..]
]
```

When you loop through it with `foreach`, `$info` will be `[.., .., ..]`.

To be honest, that array structure is also rather insane. Simplify it to this:

```
$unFilteredInfo = array();
while ($row = CDB::GetAssoc($lrs)) {
    $unFilteredInfo[] = $row;
}
```

Then:

```
foreach ($unFilteredInfo as $info) {
    echo $info['LINE1'];
    ...
}
```

Or just do the `echo` in the first loop to begin with.

Comment: Your answer make me laughing, Im not saying is wrong.

Comment: Yep, that worked perfect, sorry for my misunderstanding!